# How to solve the sum of values in a column in a datagridview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim Sum As Integer = 0
For i = 1 To DGV.Rows.Count + 1
    Sum += DGV.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value
Next
Label7.Text = Sum.ToString()
```

Result:

[image: See result here]

Comment: Arrays start at index 0 not 1. Look at how you index the column. You pass the index 3 to reference the fourth column. Why do you start at index 1 to reference the Rows array?

Comment: Note that you also have a `NewRow` in your DGV. Take that into consideration while looping the `Rows` collection.

Comment: Are you using an underlying collection in the datagridview? If so I would recommend leveraging it rather than the DGV.

Comment: What is the .DataSource of your DataGridView?

Answer (score 0):

This works well for me.
Going through every row and exclude new rows.

```
Dim SResult As Integer = 0
For Each SF As DataGridViewRow In DGV.Rows
    If SF.IsNewRow = False Then
        SResult += SF.Cells(3).Value
    End If
Next
Label7.Text = SResult
```